# Null output from Transform function of Spatialite

Tags: sql, spatialite, database, sqlite

I am using Spatialite, an extension of SQlite and I have some problems running the transform function.

According to the Spatialite functions page (http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.2.0.html), the transform function should take in a geometry object and an integer of the SRID that I want to transform an object to, and then output a geometry.

I did the following query, but I'm always given a NULL output.

```
SELECT Transform ((SELECT Geometry FROM healthierdining), 3414)
```

I have checked that Geometry FROM healthierdining is indeed of type geometry, and yes, I have PROJ.4 version Rel. 4.6.1 installed. What could possibly be wrong with this code?

Comment: Is EPSG:3414 defined in your spatialite? Check `SELECT * FROM spatial_ref_sys WHERE srid = 3414`

Comment: SQL is wrong, use `SELECT Transform(Geometry, 3414) FROM healthierdining;`

Comment: @Zoltan it returns "no such table spatial_ref_sys". What should I do to define it my spatialite?

Comment: I suppose it is an installation issue, Go through the installation guide for your operating system.